# Revert to previous commit and ignore any uncommited changes in git

Tags: git, commit, revert

I'm a beginner with git and having some problems while trying to revert everything to the last time I committed. I don't mind losing any of the changes I just want to undo everything. I tried this:

```
git revert b78da61000bc049133f4a5f7df6ddb3b6407454f
```

But I'm getting

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge. 
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I don't want to commit these new changes because obviously they don't work and I just want to get rid of them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

git revert means to create a new commit which 'undoes' the changes done in the specified commit.

You want:

```
git reset --hard <commit>
```

(This removes any uncommitted changes from the working directory, and sets the current branch to the specified commit)

Note that reset modifies history. So if you have already pushed those commits, it's not advised to just remove them by resetting them, because when you (force) push the new history, others have to rebase their changes onto the new history.

See [man git-reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) and [Reset Demystified](http://git-scm.com/2011/07/11/reset.html)

Comment: So basically the difference is that if I commit first and than revert I would still have the changes in my history, but with reset they are completely removed?

Comment: Yes. Note that reset should only be done if that history is not already published. If it's already published (and others have worked o n it, then revert might be a better option)

Answer (score 2):

### git reset --hard HEAD

If you just want to remove all changes in your working copy you can do so with:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

HEAD is the last commit in your current branch (assuming that you're IN a branch)

### git revert is not what you want

git revert doesn't do what you're trying to do, it is used to undo a commit (to commit the exact opposite of an existing commit so that the net effect is to remove it, whilst keeping history).